# Draw an item from coordinates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, map-drawing

Is it possible to draw a line or to draw a triangle or another figure by digit the coordinates of the vertex?

I use QGIS 1.8 on windows 7 system.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can digitize using the keyboard to enter the vertex coordinates using a plugin called ["NumericalDigitize"](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/numericalDigitize/).

You can add this plugin using the Python plugin manager. The last version 0.2 requires QGIS 2.0, so maybe it's a good time to upgrade. You can use an earlier version if you want to stick to QGIS 1.8.

NumericalDigitize adds a new button to enter coordinates using the keyboard. Tell me if you don't know how to use it.

Comment: I will try it. I think I will upgrade to QGIS 2.0 in few weeks, I am waiting for possible bug fixes only